# Java create Unixtime and MySQL reconvert?

Tags: java, mysql

i have a small java app that imports dates into a mysql database i use this code to convert the time:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.set(2012, 2, 30, 0, 0); // for 2012-03-30 00:00
unixtime = cal.getTimeInMillis();
unixtime = unixtime / 1000;
System.out.println(unixtime); // => 1333062005
```

If i run:

```
SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(1333062005) AS T1;
```

i get:

> 2012-03-30 01:00:05

I think the 5 seconds are some rounding differences because milliseconds to seconds. But why its 01:00 and not 00:00 ?

Any Idea?

Answer (score 0):

Mysql has different Timezone than Java. Please set your timezone as:

```
SET time_zone = 'America/New_York';
```

Comment: Thats bad, i am not able to change the mysql part. Can i change anything in the java part. My time_zone is gmt+1

Comment: what output you see for this:
SELECT @@global.time_zone, @@session.time_zone;
and compare it with the one in Jave using:

TimeZone tz = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeZone();
System.out.println("TimeZone: "+tz.getDisplayName());

Comment: The output of Java is GMT+1

Comment: And "SYSTEM" is "[~] date +%Z" CET